# pycharm TypeError: Additional arguments should be named <dialectname>_<argument>, got 'autoload'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am new to python and my program had been working and now I am getting this error -

```
File "C:\Repos\caers-api-to-cedars\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\base.py", line 599, in _validate_dialect_kwargs
raise TypeError(
TypeError: Additional arguments should be named <dialectname>_<argument>, got 'autoload'
```

my packages are

```
certifi==2022.5.18.1
pytz==2022.1
requests>=2.31.0
click==8.1.3
cx-oracle==8.3.0
sqlalchemy==2.0.25
```

I have tried older sqlalchemy packages and get this error

```
sqlalchemy.exc.DatabaseError: (cx_Oracle.DatabaseError) DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "C:\app\client\xxxx\product\12.2.0\client_2\oci.dll is not the correct architecture". See https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html for help
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/4xp6)
```

I am at a loss on what to change or add.

I'm not sure if this is enough to recreate it. I don't know where the failure is taking place. This is the main part of my code -

```
import click
import cx_Oracle
import requests
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import null, select, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
```

main class

```
class CaersToCedarsDB:

def __init__(self, env="DEV"):

    self.Base = None
    self.engine = None
    self.db_session = None

    self.logger = logger
    self.connection = None
    self.cursor = None

    self.token: str = ""
    self.token_type = None

    self.db_view_list: list = []
    self.features_dict: dict = {}

    self.jenkins_pass = "test" 
    self.env = env

    instant_client_dir = r"O:\ORANT\instantclient_21_3"
```

connect to database

```
def create_db_connection(self, env, user, password):
    if env == "PROD":
        db = "PRD1"
    else:
        db = "BETA"

    self.engine = create_engine(f"oracle+cx_oracle://{user}:{password}@{self.database_server}")

    self.db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False,
                                                  autoflush=False,
                                                  bind=self.engine))
    self.Base = declarative_base()
    self.Base.query = self.db_session.query_property()
```

program start

```
def start(self, user, password, caers_user, caers_pass):
    
    self.create_db_connection(env=self.env, user=user, password=password)

    self.init_db()

def run_data_importer(env: str, db_pass: str, db_user: str, caers_pass: 
str, caers_user: str):
updater = CaersToCedarsDB(env=f"{env}")
updater.start(user=db_user, password=db_pass, caers_pass=caers_pass, caers_user=caers_user)


if __name__ == "__main__":
run_data_importer()
```

Comment: Please give a [mre].

Comment: I'm not sure what you want but this is the only place autoload is referenced, I've put it to false and removed it all I got were different errors `class Emission_Pt_Detail(Base):
   __table__ = Table('EMISSION_PT_DETAIL', Base.metadata,
                     autoload=True, autoload_with=engine, schema="deq")`

Comment: this is my connectionstring `engine = create_engine(f"oracle+cx_oracle://user:password@server")

db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False,
                                         autoflush=False,
                                         bind=engine))
Base = declarative_base()
Base.query = db_session.query_property()`

Comment: Please [edit] the question to provide the means for someone else to recreate the issue locally.

Comment: Use the latest version of cx_Oracle, now called python-oracledb.  It's been available for a couple of years.  See the [release announcement](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a). Also see [Using SQLAlchemy 2.0 with python-oracledb for Oracle Database](https://medium.com/oracledevs/using-the-development-branch-of-sqlalchemy-2-0-with-python-oracledb-d6e89090899c).

Answer (score 0):

`autoload=` was deprecated in SQLAlchemy 1.4 and removed in SQLAlchemy 2.0. Testing your code under SQLA 1.4 shows:

> RemovedIn20Warning: The autoload parameter is deprecated and will be removed in version 2.0.  Please use the autoload_with parameter, passing an engine or connection.

TL;DR - remove the `autoload=True` argument.

Comment: I removed all the `autoload=True` and the error I get now is `sqlalchemy.exc.DatabaseError: (cx_Oracle.DatabaseError) DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "C:\app\client\CBA036\product\12.2.0\client_2\oci.dll is not the correct architecture". See https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html for help
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/4xp6)
`

Comment: That is a totally different issue. Try using the newer [oracledb](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/dialects/oracle.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.oracle.oracledb) driver in "thin client" mode instead.

Comment: A reference on python-oracledb Thin vs Thick modes and DPI-1047 is the python-oracledb documention [Initializing python-oracledb](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/initialization.html).  (cx_Oracle is equivalent to python-oracledb Thick mode, if you decide to use the older version cx_Oracle).

Answer (score 0):

The first error messages I received was due to having `autoload=True`. The newer version of SQLAlchemy does not support this. Once I removed it, I got a different error message - `sqlalchemy.exc.DatabaseError: (cx_Oracle.DatabaseError) DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "C:\app\client\CBA036\product\12.2.0\client_2\oci.dll is not the correct architecture". See https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html for help (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/4xp6)`. I was running an Oracle 32 bit client and my Python was 64 bit. To resolve the error, I uninstalled the Python 64 bit and went to a 32 bit version. I hope these solutions will help others.